# Using different units in SVG

Tags: svg

I have a simple SVG which I need to make responsive horizontally. The rectangle (and SVG) should expand to 100% of the width, but the circles should always have a diameter of 10px. The circles should also be distributed evenly on the horizontal axis (0%, 33%, 66%, 100%)

To get the ball rolling here is the basic SVG (no responsiveness yet..)

```
<svg height="10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g fill="#333" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <rect y="3" width="245" height="4" rx="2"/>
    <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5"/>
    <circle cx="80" cy="5" r="5"/>
    <circle cx="160" cy="5" r="5"/>
    <circle cx="240" cy="5" r="5"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I've also setup a Codepen at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GBNadz

Any tips on where to start? Is this possible with SVG?

Comment: you'd have to have 2 svg one responsive and one not for the static circle, or resize the circle with javascript dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [unit identifiers](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#Units) to specify coordinates and lengths. Writing `cx="5"` and `cx="5px"` is equivalent. What you cannot do is use the CSS `calc()` function; and there are some special attributes like `viewBox` and `transform` that look like they define length values, but actually do not. For your use case, where you need to shift the outer dots a bit to the middle, a combination of percentage coordinates and unitless `transform="translate(...)` does the trick.

```html
<svg height="10" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g fill="#333" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <rect y="3" width="100%" height="4" rx="2"/>
    <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5"/>
    <circle cx="33%" cy="5" r="5"/>
    <circle cx="66%" cy="5" r="5"/>
    <circle cx="100%" cy="5" r="5" transform="translate(-5)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```